# Не могу передать изображения на сервер

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post, fileupload

Есть несколько полей такого типа `<input type="file" name="file1">`в которых я выбираю изображения. Мне нужно с помощью ajax залить их на **imgur**, а ссылку вернуть в ответе. Проблема в том, что не знаю как правильно передать изображения в $_FILES['img'].

**JS**

```
$.each($("[name=file"+i+"]"), function(i, obj){
            $.each(obj.files,function(i,file){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'imgur.php',
                    data: file,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data != '') {
                            arr.push(data); // записываю ответ в массив
                        }
                    }
                })
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_FILES['img'])) {
        $file = $_FILES['img'];
        if ($file['name'] != '') {
            $filename = $file['tmp_name'];
            $client_id = "***************";
            $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
            $data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
            $pvars   = array('image' => base64_encode($data));
            $timeout = 30;
            $curl    = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
            $out = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close ($curl);
            $pms = json_decode($out,true);
            $url=$pms['data']['link'];
            if ($url!="") {
                $url = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $url );
                $imgname = preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/','',$file['name']);
                echo $url;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте так:

```
   <form id="upload">
   <input type="file" name="file">
   <button type="submit">Upload</button>
   </form>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#upload").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form=($(this)[0]);
        var formdata=new FormData(form);
        $.ajax({
                    url:'url.php',//обработчик
                    type:'POST',
                    data:formdata,
                    enctype:'multipart/form-data',
                    processData:false,
                    contentType:false,
                    success:function(data){
                    //в случае успешной загрузки
                    },

                    error: function (data) {
                    //в случае ошибки
                    }
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

В обработчике проверяться с помощью $_POST['file']

Comment: Если одно изображение передаю то работает, а если их несколько? У меня в форме несколько полей с name="file1" несколько с name="file2"

Comment: делайте multiple form. <input type="file" name="file[]"> <input type="file" name="file[]"> <input type="file" name="file[]">. Это будет массив.

Comment: я уже сделал, все работает)

Comment: рад был помочь.

Answer (score 2):

Сделай через Guzzle, вот пример

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133244/upload-file-using-guzzle-6-to-api-endpoint

Comment: Сложная штука, много времени уйдет. Мне нужно до завтра это сделать. Больше вариантов нет как решить эту задачу?

Comment: Это самый простой вариант, так как в Guzzle все уже реализовано. Да и чего сложного в том примере? Последовательно наполняешь массив контентом и описанием файлов

Comment: с установкой проблемы, не могу понять как его установить на сервер.

Comment: Может с помощью FormData можно как то отправить?

Comment: Попробуй вот это http://stackoverflow.com/a/15200804